# how to load a partial view inside an anchor tag which has been generated via Ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I have a form with a dropdownlist. When selecting an option, I make an ajax call to dynamically add a list of links in the view. When I click on one of the links, I want to update the existing page with a partial view returned by the `PostListSubCategory()` method.

Currently, clicking on one of the links does a redirect and shows the partial view in a new page. How can I update the the existing page?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function GetSubCategory(_categoryId) {
    var procemessage = "<a='0'> Please wait...</a>";
    $("#SubCategoryID").html(procemessage).show();
    var url = "/Posts/GetSubCategoryById/";

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: { categoryid: _categoryId },
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            var markup = "";
            for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                var num = data[x].Text;
                markup += "<a href='/posts/postlistsubcategory?subcategoryid=" + data[x].Text + "'>" + data[x].Text + "</a><br />";
                // markup += "<a href=" + Url.Action("postlistsubcategory", new { subcategoryid = num });
            }
            $("#SubCategoryID").html(markup).show();
        },
        error: function (reponse) {
            alert("error : " + reponse);
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Posts/PostListCategory",
        data: { categoryid: _categoryId },
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#postList").html(data).show();                
        },
        error: function (reponse) {
            alert("error : " + reponse);
        }
    });
}
</script>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{    
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.CategoryModel, new SelectList(Model.CategoryModel,       "CategoryId", "Name"), new { @id = "ddlcategory", @style = "width:200px;", @onchange = "javascript:GetSubCategory(this.value);" })
<br />
<br />
<div id="SubCategoryID" name="SubCategoryID" style="width: 200px"></div>

<br /><br />
```

}

In the controller

```
public PartialViewResult PostListSubCategory(string subcategoryid)
    {
        if (subcategoryid == null)
        {
            return PartialView(db.Posts.ToList());
        }
        return PartialView("PostList", db.Posts.Include(i => i.SubCategory).Where(p => p.SubCategory.Name == subcategoryid));
    }
```

Comment: Your returning a partial view, not json so `for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++)` makes no sense. Either return a partial view with the html you want and add it to the DOM, or return json (an array of the names you want to generate the links for)

Comment: The first Ajax function is from a different `PartialView`, generating the list of subcategories within the selected category and at the same time loading `PartialViewResult PostListSubCategory`

Comment: What?? What is the method you ajax call is calling if not the one your have shown (and why are you showing that method if its not relevant). And your creating a link with a `href` attribute so of course it will redirect (that's what links do)

Comment: My best guess is that what your really asking is that you want to dynamically add links with you ajax call, and then when you click on one of those links you want to update the existing page with a partial view returned by the `PostListSubCategory()` method?

Comment: OK, I'll add an answer to show how to do this (and also edit you question to make it a bit clearer what your wanting to do). Give me 30 min.

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to make it as clear as possible, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently dyamically generating links with an `href` attribute so clicking on them will do a redirect. You need to handle the click event of those links using event delegation and then use ajax to update the existing DOM. There a some other bad practices in your code and I suggest you use the following

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    // no need to override the id attribute and use Unobtrusive Javascript (don't pollute markup with behavior)
    @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.CategoryModel, new SelectList(Model.CategoryModel,"CategoryId", "Name"))
}
<div id="SubCategoryID"></div> // no point adding a name attribute
<div id="postList"></div>

var subcategories = $('#SubCategoryID');
$('#CategoryModel').change(function() {
    var url = '@Url.Action("GetSubCategoryById", "Posts")'; // don't hard code url's
    var category = $(this).val();
    subcategories.empty(); // clear any existing links
    $.post(url, { categoryid: category }, function(data) { // this could be a GET?
        $.each(data, function(index, item) {
            subcategories.append($('<a></a>').text(item).attr('href','#').addClass('subcategory')); // see note below
        });
    });
});
```

Note: Since your ajax only needs one property to generate the links (the value to display in the link), then your `GetSubCategoryById()` should be returning `IEnumerable<string>` not a collection of complex objects (you current code suggest your returning other data which you never use). If you do need to return a collection of objects, then change the above to use `.text(item.Text)`. The above code will generate

```
<a href="#" class="subcategory">.....</a>
```

for each item you return. Then add an additional script to handle the `.click()` event of the links (since the links are dynamically added, you need event delegation using the `.on()` method)

```
var posts = $('#postList');
$('#SubCategoryID').on('click', '.subcategory', function() {
    var url = '@Url.Action("postlistsubcategory", "posts")';
    var subcategory = $(this).text();
    posts.load(url, { subcategoryid: subcategory });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I modified it a bit and it works fine now